# angular filter with null error

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

```
<select ng-option='...' ng-model='myFilter.username'>
<option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

when i choose the all, `myFilter.username` is null, as the angular just render the empty-string value option to null option.

so when I use it for filter:

```
1. <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:myFilter.username"></li>
2. <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{username:myFilter.username}"></li>
3. <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:myFilter"></li>
```

the 1st  will get my all users, but 2nd and 3rd are not, filter with no-empty-object with null-atr, it gets nothing

Comment: What's wrong with the first one? Can you not use it for some reason?

Comment: eg:  UserList= [{"username": "abc12", address: "13"}, {"username": "xyz13", address: "Los"}].  If i use two filters: username and address, then how can I filter the username with 13, but not adress?